# Unable to change the query in codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, pagination

I m using codeigniter pagination class, it works fine when a controller first load, on the next load it not change the data.

Here is my controller:

```
class test extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct() {
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->model("getdata");
    $this->load->library("pagination");
}
public function read($page=0){
    $this->load->view('header');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/test/read";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->getdata->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $data["results"] = $this->getdata->basic($config["per_page"],$page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('readarea',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
 }
};  
?>
```

Here is my Model:

```
<?php
class getdata extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

   public function record_count() {
     return $this->db->count_all("table1");
   }


    public function basic($limit,$start){
$this->db->limit($limit,$start);    
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT table1.id,table1.post_id,table1.author,table1.quest,table1.first_name,table2.last_name,table2.pic,table2.userid FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.post_id = table2.id ORDER BY table1.id DESC");
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result();     
    }
    return FALSE;
    }

};
?>
```

NOTE: Links are created, but not get the next data from database...

Answer (score 0):

Try below query in model.

```
   public function basic($limit,$start){

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT table1.id,table1.post_id,table1.author,table1.quest,table1.first_name,table2.last_name,table2.pic,table2.userid FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.post_id = table2.id ORDER BY table1.id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
           return $query->result();     
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change this function to this

```
public function read($page = null){
    $this->load->view('header');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/test/read";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->getdata->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 5;

    $this->pagination->cur_page = $page; // add this line into it i hope this work

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $data["results"] = $this->getdata->basic($config["per_page"],$page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('readarea',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
 }
};
```